# Multiplying polynomials: Unexpected output

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, polynomial-math

I essentially tried finding (x+1)^2 (inputed as 1 1 for powers of polynomial 1 and 2, 1 1 for the coeff of P1 and 1 1 for coeff of P2) using the code given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n;

    printf("enter the highest powers of P1 and P2\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);          //m= power of P1, n=power of P2

    int a[m],b[n],c[m+n];         //a[m]= coeff of P1, b[n]= coeffof P2

    printf("enter the values\n");



    for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)         //takes coeff of P1 as input
      { printf("a[%d]=\n",i);     //array index are same as the power of x
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      }

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)         //takes coeff of P2 as input
      { printf("b[%d]=\n",i);     //array index are same as the power of x
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
      }

    for(int i=0;i<=m+n;i++)       //to initialize array c to zero
      { printf("c[%d]=\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&c[i]);
      }

    for(int k=0;k<=m+n;k++)       //k= power of x in the polynomial= array index  
      {  for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
          c[k]=c[k]+a[i]*b[k-i];  //for fixed k, summing a[i]*b[k-i]
      }

    for(int i=0;i<=m+n;i++)
       printf("c[%d]=%d\n",i,c[i]);

}
```

I got my answer as  2293469x^2 + 2x + 1. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)` --> `for(int i=0;i<m;i++)`, same as others.

Comment: I'll start with this LOOP `for(int k=0;k<=m+n;k++)`. Are you sure you know what are you trying to do there?

Comment: @SouravGhosh or declare array bound `m+1` maybe more suitable given the problem

Comment: You're using a `scanf` loop to initialize an array to zeroes? Why not just assign zeroes?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry. I am a newbie

Comment: @interjay can't do that. my compiler shows error and states that variable sized object may not be initialized.

Comment: @Michi Yes. K denotes the power of x. c[k], here denotes the coefficient of the new x^k in the new polynomial.  `for(int k=0;k<=m+n;k++)` is being used to fix k first. With k fixed, `for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)` is being used to vary i to sum up a[i]*b[k-i].

Answer (score 0):

The is a misconception, the following would do

int a[m+1], b[n+1], c[m+1+n+1];

Valid indices then would be 0..m and 0..n.

Normal practice would be to use 2 2 and `<m`, `<n`.

And there is index out of range in a and b:

```
for(int k = 0; k <= m+n; k++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        c[k] = c[k] + a[i] * b[k-i];
    }
}
```

Comment: But why is using  `for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)` incorrect?

Comment: Actually, `int a[m+1], b[n+1], c[m+n+1];` would suffice.

Comment: `a[i]` and `b[k-i]` receive indices between 0 and m+n, the latter being out of range.  But `<=m` would do.